# Send MouseWheel messages to System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser

Tags: winforms, webbrowser-control, mousewheel

I wanted to forward `MouseWheel` events produced at the form level, so that they would be processed by an embedded `WebBrowser` control, even when that control didn't have the focus.

Here is what I have done:

1. Implemented `IMessageFilter.PreFilterMessage`.
2. Registered the filter it with `Application.AddMessageFilter`.
3. In the filter, listen for `WM_MOUSEWHEEL` messages.
4. Forward the messages using `SendMessage` to the target control (in my case `WebBrowser`).

In code, this looks like this:

```
bool IMessageFilter.PreFilterMessage(ref Message m)
{
    if (m.Msg == 0x20A)     //  WM_MOUSEWHEEL
    {
        if (this.target != null)
        {
            var handle = this.target.Handle;
            Native.SendMessage (handle, m.Message, m.WParam, m.LParam);
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

// Registering the message filter:

System.Windows.Forms.Application.AddMessageFilter (this);

// Win32 code:

protected static class NativeMethods
{
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport ("user32.dll")]
    public static extern System.IntPtr SendMessage(System.IntPtr hWnd, System.Int32 Msg, System.IntPtr wParam, System.IntPtr lParam);
}
```

This does not work. Nothing happens.

However, if instead of a `WebBrowser` I specify a `Panel` as the target, then this works wonderfully well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Investigating with Spy++ revealed that the `WebBrowser` control in WinForms is using several layers of containers to wrap the real IE component:

```
System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser
  Shell Embedding
    Shell DocObject View
      Internet Explorer_Server
```

Sending the events to any container won't have any effect. The `WM_MOUSEWHEEL` events have to be sent to the `Internet Explorer_Server` handle in order for this to work.

Here is the modified code, which finds the IE component by digging into the containers:

```
bool IMessageFilter.PreFilterMessage(ref Message m)
{
    if (m.Msg == 0x20A)     //  WM_MOUSEWHEEL
    {
        if (this.target != null)
        {
            var handle = this.target.Handle;
            handle = NativeMethods.FindWindowEx (handle, IntPtr.Zero, "Shell Embedding", null);
            handle = NativeMethods.FindWindowEx (handle, IntPtr.Zero, "Shell DocObject View", null);
            handle = NativeMethods.FindWindowEx (handle, IntPtr.Zero, "Internet Explorer_Server", null);
            Native.SendMessage (handle, m.Msg, m.WParam, m.LParam);
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

protected static class NativeMethods
{
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport ("user32.dll")]
    public static extern System.IntPtr SendMessage(System.IntPtr hWnd, System.Int32 Msg, System.IntPtr wParam, System.IntPtr lParam);

    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport ("user32.dll")]
    public static extern System.IntPtr FindWindowEx(System.IntPtr hwndParent, System.IntPtr hwndChildAfter, string className, string windowName);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Pierre's answer works for me (can't up vote as not enough reputation). However, it requires a tweak to work in VB.NET so I thought I'd post in case there's anyone stuck on this point:

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

Public Class Form1 Implements IMessageFilter

    Public Sub New()

        ' This call is required by the designer.
        InitializeComponent()

        ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
        System.Windows.Forms.Application.AddMessageFilter(Me)

    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Me.WebBrowser1.Navigate("D:\Development\test3.html")
    End Sub

    Private Function IMessageFilter_PreFilterMessage(ByRef m As Message) As Boolean Implements IMessageFilter.PreFilterMessage

        If m.Msg = &H20A Then
            '  WM_MOUSEWHEEL

            If m.HWnd <> 0 Then
                Dim handle = m.HWnd
                handle = NativeMethods.FindWindowEx(handle, IntPtr.Zero, "Shell Embedding", Nothing)
                handle = NativeMethods.FindWindowEx(handle, IntPtr.Zero, "Shell DocObject View", Nothing)
                handle = NativeMethods.FindWindowEx(handle, IntPtr.Zero, "Internet Explorer_Server", Nothing)
                NativeMethods.SendMessage(handle, m.Msg, m.WParam, m.LParam)
                Return True
            End If

        End If

        Return False

    End Function

    Protected NotInheritable Class NativeMethods
        Private Sub New()
        End Sub
        <System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")> _
        Public Shared Function SendMessage(hWnd As System.IntPtr, Msg As System.Int32, wParam As System.IntPtr, lParam As System.IntPtr) As System.IntPtr
        End Function

        <System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")> _
        Public Shared Function FindWindowEx(hwndParent As System.IntPtr, hwndChildAfter As System.IntPtr, className As String, windowName As String) As System.IntPtr
        End Function
    End Class


End Class
```

Comment: Apart from translating from C# to VB, what was the tweak you had to do?

Comment: Hi Pierre. Just a couple and probably just related to the things that make VB.NET and C# different. I originally ran your code through the code conversion tool at Developerfusion but it didn't work straight away. One thing was to replace this.target with m.HWnd; the other was to replace m.Message with m.Msg. On that second point I wondered if it was a typo in your original C# example? Cheers, Robin

Comment: Yes, indeed, the `m.Msg` was a typo on my part. Sorry for that; I edited my answer to get it straight.