# How To Maintain FlowLayoutPanel Focus for MouseWheel Scrolling

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms

I have a flowlayoutpanel that adds richtextbox controls filled with data. These controls are automatically set to "Read Only = True" and are autosized, with no visible scrollbars.

The problem I have is that if I try to use my mousewheel to scroll down the flowlayoutpanel, and my cursor touches a richtextbox, the richtextbox steals focus and prevent further scrolling on the flowlayoutpanel.

I have Googled answers and I have tried them all. Including setting focus of flowlayoutpanel within the mouseenter event, click event, and gotfocus event of the richtextbox. Including sending a mousewheel message from the richtextbox to the flowlayoutpanel. None of this works.

The only thing that does work is disabling the richtextbox but this is not a viable solution because it removes the ability to add colors to the richtextbox which is vital.

Is there any way to prevent a richtextbox from stealing focus of the parent flowlayoutpanel?

Comment: That's not possible, the RTBs always gain focus and they have a use for the mouse wheel message themselves.  You need to customize the RTB class, deriving your own to override the WndProc() method.  And forwarding the message to their parent with SendMessage.  Examples are [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17228033/send-mousewheel-messages-to-system-windows-forms-webbrowser) and [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/8fa189a9-8803-4c41-86bf-b50a53e42cf5/getting-mouse-wheel-to-scroll-tab?forum=winforms)

Comment: Well, it is possible and relatively simple. Make a Custom Control derived from FlowLayoutPanel, make it implement `IMessageFilter` to trap `WM_MUSEHWHEEL` and `WM_MOUSEWHEEL`. When you intercept those messages (which you get before the intended recipient(s) - your RichTextBox Contols - receive them), use `SendMessage()` to send the message to *yourself* and return true. You have to check whether `RectangleToScreen(ClientRectangle).Contains(MousePosition)`, because you may act on messages that are not meant for the Panel's child Controls.

Comment: You can modify as described the custom FlowLayoutPanel class shown here: [Hiding the Scrollbar while allowing scrolling with the Mouse Wheel in a FlowLayoutPanel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67855814/7444103) - You don't need to override WndProc for this, just the `PrefilterMessage` method is required -- I suggest to add a Property, say: `public bool TrapMouseWheel { get; set; } = false;` and `if (!TrapMouseWheel) return false;` on top of  `PrefilterMessage`, so you can switch this feature on/off, when required

Comment: I think it's great to have received some responses but again, this is not working. I am using .NET 6 and currently trying the WndProc override. I have a custom class that inherits RTB and passes mousewheel messages to flowlayoutpanel. The problem is, the messages are not being passed. As soon as I scroll over a richtextbox, the flowlayoutpanel stops scrolling. I have made sure to add the new custom control to the FLP instead of the native RTB.

Comment: Try what I suggested. I can assure you it works as described -- The Custom Control class I've linked it's mostly already functional for this, you have just to remove everything related to the `WndProc` override, keep the `IMessageFilter` implementation and - as mentioned - check whether the `MousePosition` is inside the FLP's `ClientRectangle`.